# How to overlap layouts/views within LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create layout that looks like this:

[image]

`Layout1`and `Layout2` are some layouts of any kind, nested in a parent `LinearLayout`. The `LinearLayout` is necessary to give both child layouts a 50% height by using `layout_weight`.

The red squares should be `Buttons` which overlap both `Layout1`and `Layout2` and are centered between the two layouts.

Of course this could achived by using `RelativeLayout` as parent instead but then I would loose the possibility to use `layout_weight`...

If I keep using `LinearLayout`, it seems to be impossible to let the buttons overlap the two other layouts.

Furthermore the buttons cannot be siblings of the two layouts but need to be nested inside a common container layout that takes care of the horizontal positioning (e.g. a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation).

**Any idea how to solve this?**

I already tried to place the buttons inside `Layout1` (or `Layout2`), place them below the bottom and use `android:clipChildren=false`, but this had no effect. The button where simple cut in half.

**Edit:**
Splitting the height between the two layouts 50/50 is just one version. Another view uses the same basic layout but splits the height 70/30 between the two layouts. The buttons should always be centered between the two layouts. Sorry for not pointing this out earlier.

Layout Code:

```
<!-- parent/root layout -->
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ... >

    <!-- Layout1 -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... />

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <LinearLayout             
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        ... >

        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />

    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- Layout2 -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**50% linearOne 50% linearTwo**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
             />
        <View
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#000" />
        <View
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#000" />
        <View
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#000" />
        <View
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

============================================================================

**70% linearOne 30% linearTwo**

**Just close your eyes Copy and paste**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context="com.ncrypted.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/relative1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <View
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                 />
            <View
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#000" />
            <View
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                />
            <View
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#000" />
            <View
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                />
            <View
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#000" />
            <View
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This works well in case the two layouts each use 50% of the height. In another screen the ratio is 70/30. Is there a solution as well? (sorry for not adding this in the question before)

Comment: @AndreiHerford check again my answer

Comment: @AndreiHerford hey Bro I have got proper solution for you about 70% / 30% Layout just check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Hm, if you don't have any restrictions besides those ones that you've described in the question, you could do it by the next way:

```
<!-- parent/root layout -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        ... >

        <!-- Layout1 -->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_weight="1"
             ... />

        <!-- Layout2 -->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ... />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"            
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        ... >

        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This works well in case the two layouts each use 50% of the height. In another screen the ratio is 70/30. Is there a solution as well? (sorry for not adding this in the question before)

Answer (score 0):

Here, this is the solution using **only Linearlayout.**

Key point is: button is consist of two part. Half top and Half bottom. And minus margin means half of your button's height.

But, please do not use this code. Use [GuideLine of ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline.html). It has percentage option, so you can implement almost evert layout you want.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#d3d3d3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#Ed1c24">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can use this:
Position the imageviews according to your requirement

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#e2e2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#Ed1c24"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This works well in case the two layouts each use 50% of the height. In another screen the ratio is 70/30. Is there a solution as well? (sorry for not adding this in the question before)

Comment: For your current requirement of 70/30 ratio, simply place the weight 1.5 in place of 1 to first Linearlayout(which is holding the background #e2e2) & for 2nd LinearLayout place the weight to 3.5 in place of 1. @AndreiHerford

Comment: or you can use weight 0.3 for 70% and 0.7 for 30% and if this helped you please upvote this answer.

Comment: the ImageView where u place is not equally placed

Comment: Did you even read the requirement of the question and first line I wrote in my answer. Read answer carefully before downvoting.

Comment: i didn't give you downvoing bro

Comment: i just past your ans in my studio and just check and i seen that 3rd imageView is not right placed

Comment: I just placed the imageViews in center of those two views and asked him to place the images according to his requirements.

Comment: Just check your answer again what m i talking to you ,automatically u understand,the last space is big compare to started space

Comment: Who so ever has down voted please explain why you have down voted my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146224/discussion-between-nd1010-and-sumit).